# swscanf implementation in casting

Tags: c++, string, casting, scanf, wstring

I am working on a project in which I need to use `swscanf()` to find out if a string value is either Decimal or Hex. After that, I am putting that value in a variable. The function is:

```
Input_String(const std::wstring& a, const StringFormat b)
{
    unsigned int Value;
    switch (b)
    {
    case Decimal:
        swscanf(string.c_str(), L"%u", &Value);
        break;
    case HexCode:
        swscanf(string.c_str(), L"%x", &Value);
        break;
    default:
        swscanf(string.c_str(), L"%u", &Value);
        break;
    }
}
```

**`StringFormat` is an enum for format checking.**

I want to create an alternative for the `swscanf()` for the case. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: _"The Minimum reproducible code for the function is"_ definitely not

Comment: @RohitNagpal the commenter want to say that you should add a [example] -- including example input, current and expected output

Comment: Either your task is ill-posed, or you did not understand it,  or you made some mistake when presenting it here. You can't _'use swscanf function to find out if the value is either Decimal or Hex.'_ For example, the number 1011 _can_ be decimal or hexadecimal, as well as sexagesimal, octal or binary - and you can not tell that by examining the string of digits; you must know in advance what the base of the number is.

Comment: You should, at the very least, correct the obvious errors in your code (as indicated in my answer).

Comment: @CiaPan It seems clear (to me, at least) that the input format is specified in the `b` argument to the function.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, it should be clear to anyone C/C++-literate. But I was not referring to the code but rather to the question, which starts with a note on _' a project in which I need to use swscanf() to find out if a string value is either Decimal or Hex.'_ And _that_ is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the errors in your code (like using `string` in place of what presumably should be `a`, and your function not having either a declared type or a return value) aside … if you only have a choice between hex and decimal, you can initialize the `format` argument to `swscanf` according to the passed enumeration type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef enum {
    Decimal, HexCode
} StringFormat;

unsigned int Input_String(const std::wstring& a, const StringFormat b)
{
    unsigned int Value;
    const wchar_t* fmt = (b == HexCode) ? L"%x" : L"%u";
    if (swscanf(a.c_str(), fmt, &Value) != 1) {
        Value = UINT_MAX; // Always check return value and handle any error!
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you *could* put that ternary expression itself as the argument:

```cpp
unsigned int Input_String(const std::wstring& a, const StringFormat b)
{
    unsigned int Value;
    if (swscanf(a.c_str(), (b == HexCode) ? L"%x" : L"%u", &Value) != 1) {
        Value = UINT_MAX; // Error condition
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Note that, in both the above code samples, some compilers will complain (issue a warning) about not using a string literal for the `format` argument to `swscanf` (MSVC does but clang-cl doesn't). However, this ***is*** valid (if unconventional) code.